# Define layout content area

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, nine-patch, android-framelayout, custom-view

[image]

I want to define the contentArea of a Frame/Linear/Relative layout so that when I do `layout.addView(view);` it only added within the boundries and the rest of the view is clipped away. Like the picture of shirt, if I want to define the boundries of shirt to be the area of content...how can I do that. Any suggestions/help?
Thanks

PS: cannot do that in 9-patch (right and bottom) as it only defines in rectangular shape, in this case shape can be anything like that of a shirt. Want to omit the white/transparent part from the contentArea.

Comment: I would suggest dropping the notion of layouts and look into [PorterDuffXfermode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffXfermode.html) or otherwise known as alpha compositing. Here is a good visualization: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/Alpha_compositing.svg/642px-Alpha_compositing.svg.png

Comment: did you try ```android:clipChildren``` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the below code :-
Just in case someone is trying to solve same problem, there is a better solution: Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap, int x, int y, int width, int height). For example, if you need to crop 10 pixels from each side of a bitmap then use this:

```
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 10, 10, originalBitmap.get
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not really something you can do.
From what i understand you can't use PorterDuff because you need to add views to this clipped container.
I would suggest an easy trick that might be useful for u. Just add an imageview on top of your Frame/RelativeLayout that has as content an image with a full transparency on the part you want to be visible and it's opaque in the area u want to clip.
Graphically speaking that way you should achieve exactly what u need.